# Primefaces Tree dragdrop Event

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces, tree

Is there a way to keep the current dragging TreeNode as a variable?
I am using drag-drop functionality at trees but I want to undo the dragdrop event at some situations.
Aaand TreeDragDropEvent is not giving me my needs like dragNodePreviousParent and dragNodePreviousRowNumber
I tried "select" event but when a node drags, this event doesnt invoke.

Can you please help me?

```
//my try
public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event){
        parentNode=selectedNode.getParent();
        selectedRowNumber=parentNode.getChildren().indexOf(selectedNode);
    }

//TreeDragDropEvent that doesnt provide my needs
public void onDragDrop(TreeDragDropEvent event) {
        TreeNode dragNode = event.getDragNode();
        TreeNode dropNode = event.getDropNode();
        int dropIndex = event.getDropIndex();
}
```

Comment: If you have the model server side, you can easily find its parent via de model. The real current parent is not something you should rely on via the client, but only 'trust' the server

Comment: Im keeping them in objects for now but I cant follow index numbers.

Comment: I'd think you can get the 'object' from the event to can you?